# Which is better, performance wise, creating one service with multiple contracts or creating a service for each contract?

Tags: performance, wcf, service

I want to create a (query) service, that directly operates on a huge database and serve multiple clients or other services.

My question is, what are the best practices? Which is better, performance wise, creating one (query) service with multiple contracts or creating a service for each contract?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter. The performance will be the same.

So go with whatever makes more sense for you. It might be easier for coming maintainers if you have one service per interface.